# Ruby update attribute and save instance in one step

Tags: ruby

Does Ruby offer a souped-up version of the assignment operator ("`=`") that allows you to collapse these two lines into one?

```
foo.bar = "woof"
foo.save
```

Comment: depending on what `foo` object is, you can do `foo.update! "woof"` :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*Ruby* does not, but I assume you're doing this in Rails, in which case you can do

```
foo.update_attributes bar: "woof"
```

Answer (score 2):

ActiveRecord allows you to update single attribute with:

```
foo.update_attribute :bar, 'woof'
```

or multiple attributes at once:

```
foo.update_attributes bar: 'woof'
```

Please note, that latter notation will perform security checks against mass assignment permissions.

Comment: Also note that the former is not equivalent to the two-line version because it skips validation.